# Why aren't my child divs scrollable and centered in columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am struggling to make my `.centerIt` divs be centered vertically, and to have the `.div1` stay scrollable after I add more `.centerIt` divs into the column.

The `.centerIt` divs have to keep their `height: 20px` and not squeeze after I add more of them.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/TyphooNN/dvwyrtp1/21/)

```css
.container {
    display: flex; 
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.div1 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 90%;
    width: 27%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.div2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 90%;
    width: 74%;
    margin: 5px;
}
.centerIt {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 20px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="centerIt"></div>
        <div class="centerIt"></div> 
        <div class="centerIt"></div> 
        <div class="centerIt"></div>
        <div class="centerIt"></div>
        <div class="centerIt"></div> 
        <div class="centerIt"></div> 
        <div class="centerIt"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work depending on your JSFiddle example. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi There !!! I ran your code on my system. I don't see any div shrinking as more are adding. Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve :) Or share an image etc

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer Please do not remove links to JSFiddle or other such sandbox links when editing a post.

Comment: the green divs doesn't centered vertically

Comment: @TylerH By mistake, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to add `min-height: 20px` to `.centerIt` instead of height and

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
```

to `.div1` styles, should do it.

[JSFiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/mdpxc4qs/1/)

Comment: Now I got some bug in your code, in this example you cant see the first "centerIt" div https://jsfiddle.net/TyphooNN/3Lvcy19s/